# Image based captcha

Tags: java, captcha

Can we implement vidoop captcha in java?

Is that secure?

What is the complexity of implementing that in java?

What should we learn to implement that in java?

Answer (score 2):

Can we implement vidoop captcha in java?
A: Yes!

Is that secure?
A: Depends on a lot of things. Both client-side and server-side.

What is the complexity of implementing that in java?
A: You need a huge database of pre-identified matches (words against images). And the randomizing function.

What should we learn to implement that in java?
A: Database management. No more, no less.

Answer (score 1):

> can we implement vidoop captcha in
>   java?

Yes, you can.

> IS that secure?

That's what captcha is supposed to do but remember nothing is perfect, however this does not mean you should not use it.

> what is the complexity of implementing
>   that in java?

It depends on experience and how much command you have in java, however, there are always tutorials on how to do that.

> what should we learn to implement that
>   in java?

You need to learn what is required to implement that, more than basics of java should suffice i think.

**[More Info Here.](http://guidesigner.net/collection-of-development/web-form-validation-tool-free-image-based-captcha-vidoopcaptcha/)**